# How do I play and record audio at the same time?

Tags: matlab, audio, impulse-response

So this question is more related to Matlab itself.

Some background info: I'm trying out the Exponential Sine Sweep method to obtain the Room Impulse Response with my laptop speakers and microphone for testing.

I can generate the Sine sweep perfectly but I have trouble playing and recording it without a lot of lag. I'm now trying to use "audioPlayerRecorder" from the Audio System Toolbox but when I do:

```
f1 = 80;       % Start frequency (Hz)
f2 = 22000;    % Stop frequency (Hz)
T = 3;         % Sweep duration in seconds
fs = 44100;    % Sampling frequency

[sweep, inverse] = ESS_generator(f1, f2, T, fs);

playRec = audioPlayerRecorder(fs);
recording = playRec(sweep);
```

I get an error on the last line saying: 
Error using coder.internal.assert (line 33)
No full-duplex audio device detected

But I know that my laptop is able to use the microphone and speakers simultaneously so I'm thinking maybe the error gets thrown because of a missing configuration?

I'm running the code on Linux with the ALSA audio drivers. I'm using external speakers through the AUX audio port, and the default laptop microphone.

Comment: I don't know if Matlab is capable of doing that. What I have done in the past is to use Matlab to play the sound, while another process (`sox` in my case) does the recording.

Comment: May be **simulink** could do that (simultaneous playback and recording)? have you checked its documentation as well ?

Comment: @MBaz , How 'real-time' is this method? Since I assume you have a delay between the playing the audio using matlab and starting the recording.

Comment: @Fat32, I'll check this out. Thanks!

Comment: @Mistergrave It is real time in the sense that both streams are playing at the specified sampling rate. There is of course a delay, but that is unrelated to the system being 'real time". See this paper for more details: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5739249/

Comment: @MBaz, have you been able to get MATLAB to simultaneously record and playback?  that would be an interesting thing to do for the purpose of system identification.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Last time I tried, I couldn't do it, but that was several years ago. These days I don't use Matlab much (I am a convert to Julia). Playing and recording simultaneously can easily be done, at least in Linux, by launching two separate processes. If you want me, I'll be happy to try again in Matlab or to provide more details on the alternatives I know.

Comment: For system identification purposes, you can easily set up a GnuRadio flowgraph to transmit and receive signals simultaneously, not only with the sound card, but with any supported hardware.

Comment: i don't have any GnuRadio.  does it playback from a `.wav` and record to a `.wav`?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Sorry, I missed your comment. Yes, GnuRadio can play back from a WAV file while recording to a WAV file. It is really quite flexible. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @Mistergrave I looked into Matlab's `audioPlayerRecorder` for a different project, and it is really quite limited, since it requires a full-duplex audio device. Have you tried using separate `audioDeviceReader` and `audioDeviceWriter` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is to do with having your speakers and microphone on different ALSA audio devices or subdevices.

You need to find the available sound cards for recording and playback on your system. The following commands will tell you this information :

```
aplay -l
arecord -l
```

You will need to define a default full duplex sound card using your choice of devices you see in the output to the above commands.

The way to define this full duplex card (made of two different soundcard devices) is to define it in your ~/.asoundrc file. [This example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69717/linux-alsa-one-sound-card-for-input-one-sound-card-for-output) shows you how to do that, however I will repeat it here.

The requirement is that you use plughw as your device name because the clocks on the two sound cards will drift and you will need resampling of some form. But you can play with this option.

So for example if you want to take input from a device on the first card (hw:0) and output to the second device on the second card (hw:1,1) then you would write the following in your ~/.asoundrc file :

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "plughw:1,1"
    capture.pcm  "plughw:0"
}
ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

Hopefully now Matlab sees a full duplex card as the default device and allows full duplex operation.

Answer (score 0):

read doc of audioPlayerRecorder
"Supported drivers for audioPlayerRecorder are platform-specific:
Windows® –– ASIO™
Mac –– CoreAudio
Linux® –– ALSA"

which means u need to install ASIO driver.
In my case, a usb microphone is also needed, because RealTek Soundcard seems cannot enable full Duplex Mode.